# How to show a div from multiple divs on which mouse is hovered using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a many div with same class `pro3` and an image with class `showcatdiv`

And this are appended on any image on wordpress page ..I want to show div with `pro3` on hover of `showcatdiv` Below is my `pro3` div

```
 <div class="pro3catProducts" style=" background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 0px solid black;
    height: 279px; left: '200'px; opacity: 0.55; padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative; top: '100'px; width: 39px; display:none;">
            <IMG class="catsmallImages" id="catsmallImages1" SRC="Images/fashion.png"  BORDER="1" ALT="" style="height: 37px; padding: 3px; width: 28px;">
            <IMG class="catsmallImages" id="catsmallImages2" SRC="Images/fashion.png"  BORDER="1" ALT="">
                </div>
```

I have written a javascript for it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ( undefined !== window.jQuery ) {
    // script dependent on jQuery

        alert("test");
        jQuery(".showcatdiv").hover(function(){ 
           //alert("test324");
    jQuery(".pro3catProducts").show();  
    });

  }
</script>
```

With this it is showing the pro3 div on every image..I want to show on that particular image ??

[image: Image One]

[image: Image Two]

First image show the image on which i want to have a hover effect ...And the second image does what i need but i just want on that perticular image and here it is showing on all images..

Comment: can you post your full html.. the part where you define `showcatdiv` clas too

Comment: What's `.showcatdiv`? The parent of `pro3catProducts`?

Comment: Also, don't do `left: '200'px`, that's just wrong - get rid of the quotation marks

Comment: theres nothing as such in showcatdiv ..theres an image ABC(example) ..onhover of ABC i want to show pro3 div

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Just tell us what you're hovering over, and what you want to display. You mention `showcatdiv` in your code and then say there's no such thing. How are we suppose to help you?

Comment: There is no relation between pro3 and showcatdiv...They both r in one div Maindiv..

Comment: Then **show us all the code**, the part you've shown makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pro3` and `showcatdiv` are both in `maindiv`, and you want to show `pro3` when you hover over `showcatdiv`, you can use CSS to achieve that:

```
.pro3 {
    display: none;
}
.showcatdiv:hover+.pro3 {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KvrGk/2/

No need for JavaScript, especially jQuery. Do however [check the support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) for the sibling selector.

Comment: But You have misunderstood this - the `showcatdiv` is visible while `pro3` is hidden by default, thus no `:hover` could be performed on `pro3` div...

Comment: "I want to show div with pro3 on hover of showcatdiv" - right, just swap it around then.

Comment: Yep, it looks nice and I like the idea of using CSS and no need of jQuery (JS at all) for this! +1

Comment: @user1145009 No worries, sometimes it's just simpler to use CSS.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no relation between pro3 and showcatdiv...They both r in one div Maindiv

seeing your comment if they are inside one div.. then use `this` reference  get parent and find `.pro3catProducts`
try this..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if ( undefined !== window.jQuery ) {
    alert("test");
    jQuery(".showcatdiv").hover(function(){ 
      jQuery(this).parent().find(".pro3catProducts").show();  //<--here
    });

 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's assume the `img` is a sibling of `pro3` div in this way:

```
<img class="showCatDiv" ... />
<div class="pro3..." ... >...</div>
```

Then the JS would be:

```
$('.showCatDiv').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.pro3').show();  
});
```

which finds their common parent and then looks for this `pro3` div to be shown.

Or

```
$('.showCatDiv').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.pro3').show();  
});
```

which relies on the `pro3` div to be the sibling of `img`.